# Can't retrieve a custom extra with the SAF

Tags: java, android, android-intent

In the `Intent` used to trigger an `android.intent.action.CREATE_DOCUMENT` action, I add a custom extra with `myIntent.putExtra("myPackage.MY_EXTRA","toto")`.

In the `onActivityResult` function, when I try to retrieve this extra with `intent.getStringExtra("myPackage.MY_EXTRA")`, I get a null `String` (`intent` is the `Intent` received as a parameter in the `onActivityResult` function).

Any idea on how I could solve my problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want is not likely to be available for *any* `startActivityForResult()` call. Putting an extra on an `Intent` sends that extra to the other activity. There is no requirement for that extra to be returned to you, and few (if any) activities will do that.

So, hold onto the data yourself, such as in a field of your activity.